# wordpress Feed Error

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I build my web sit by wordpress. When i try to add feed function some issue occur.I use chrome visit the feed,log is :

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 134 at column 16: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x08 0xE8 0xBF 0x90
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I have checked the the blank of header.php.I also use fix rss plug-in, but it still can't be fix it. How do I check which file cause the error? my feed url is : http://www.songyang.net/feed/

Comment: Thanks for your advice. MrZebra's answer already solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the page [here](http://www.songyang.net/unity3d-fingergestures-move/) has invalid UTF-8 characters in it.  The problem lies here:

首先，我们需要创建一个场景。接着在场景中放放置一个灯光, 最后在场景中放置一个物体, 将它上面挂载一个我们创建的组件。

**bad character here**运行程序后, 场景中会出现一个 `UI` 按钮, 点击它移动立方体。移动的路径通过两个动画拼接完成。

Delete the characters around there and re-type them, that should remove the invalid character.
It tells you where the bad character is because it renders the page up until the character.  If you want, you can actually see the character by copy/pasting the section of text into a UTF-8 file in Notepad++.  In this case, it comes out as a "BS" character!

[bad character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUMLG.png).